# Difference in creation of thread using Runnable and Thread?

Tags: java

This code is working fine but if I use the constructor Thread(name) in 6th line instead of Thread(this,name) it is not working I just want to know what makes the difference?

```
public class threadtest implements Runnable{
    Thread t;

    public threadtest(String name)
    {
        System.out.println("satheesh");
        Thread t=new Thread(this,name);
        t.start();
        t=null;
        //System.out.println(this+"\n"+t);
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("satheesh");
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
            try{
                System.out.println("satheesh");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.print(Thread.currentThread());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        threadtest ob=new threadtest("satheesh");       
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please clarify, and check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/java-implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread

Comment: You might find reading the code for Thread interesting, pariticularly the run() method.

Answer (score 6):

There's two ways to create a thread:

1. Subclass `Thread`, override `run`, and then create an instance of your subclass
2. Extend `Runnable` and give it to a thread to "run" it

Your code does #2 - you implemented `Runnable`, so you must give it to a thread to "run" it.

> if I use the constructor `Thread(name)` in 6th line instead of `Thread(this,name)` it is not working I just want to know what makes the difference?

The difference is that:

- `Thread t= new Thread(this,name);`

  Creates a new thread that is given your `Runnable` (`this`) to run when it is started.
- `Thread t= new Thread(name);`

  Creates a new thread is ***not*** given any `Runnable` to run. So the thread does nothing when it is started.

Answer (score 3):

Writing `new Thread("somename")` creates a thread that won't do anything.
(since you never provided anything for it to run)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is the same as this question: ["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/java-implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)

Another good source of information is this thread on coderanch.com http://www.coderanch.com/t/233370/threads/java/Thread-vs-Runnable

Comment: Title is similar but question seems to be different.

Comment: @jzd the uploader changed his question after I posted. Totally different question now :/.

Answer (score 0):

u r using runnable interface for creating thread,if we use runnable interface then in thread constructor we pass runnable object refernce and the name of thread.when u use thread(name),its not called start() but when u create thread(this ,name) it fullfill the requirement of runnable thread and start start().

Comment: Please see this: [writing good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple (and understandable) misunderstanding of what the different Thread constructors do.  There are two constructors in question:

1. [Thread(Runnable, String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String%29) creates a `Thread`, assigns its name to the `String` and specifies that it should run the `Runnable`.
2. [Thread(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String%29) calls the general constructor with special magic arguments of [Thread (null, null, name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.ThreadGroup,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String%29).  This creates a new `Thread` but it will run the method in the `Thread`, not any provided `Runnable`.  As a result, if you call `t.start()`, it's going to call the Thread's `run()` method.

So, a simple rewrite of the code gets you what you want:

```
public class threadtest extends Thread { // [sic] on the capitalization

    public threadtest(String name) {
        System.out.println("satheesh");
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("satheesh");
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
        try {
            System.out.println("satheesh");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        threadtest ob = new threadtest("satheesh");
        // The following will call the correct run method now
        ob.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1st, we should knew Thread(String s) vs Thread(Runnable r, String s) different purpose.

The different is *Thread(String s)* **we sent "value"** in bracket () to constructor that implements Runnable but *Thread(Runnable r, String s)* **we give a thread name** to String s to the thread constructor that implements Runnable.

Here the same code that implements Runnable via Thread (Runnable r, String s).

```
public class threadtest implements Runnable{
Thread t;
threadtest th;

public threadtest(){}

public threadtest(String name)
{
System.out.println("satheesh");
Thread t=new Thread(th, name); //satheesh,name of thread, gave to name
t.start(); //2nd thread that will start run() method in void run()
//t=null;
//System.out.println(this+"\n"+t);
}
public void run(){
 System.out.println("satheesh");
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
try{
System.out.println("satheesh");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.print(Thread.currentThread());
}
catch(Exception e)  { System.out.println(e); }
}
}
public static void main(String args[]){

//ob is Runnable object that will send his empty value ()
threadtest ob = new threadtest(); //to default constructor threadtest() above

//satheesh is name of main thread that we will send to String name in Thread t=new Thread(th, name);
Thread th = new Thread(ob, "satheesh");
th.start();  //1st thread that will instruct to send satheesh
}
}
```

output:

```
satheesh
satheesh
Thread[satheesh,5,main]satheesh
Thread[satheesh,5,main]satheesh
Thread[satheesh,5,main]satheesh
Thread[satheesh,5,main]satheesh
Thread[satheesh,5,main]satheesh
Thread[satheesh,5,main]satheesh
Thread[satheesh,5,main]satheesh
Thread[satheesh,5,main]satheesh
Thread[satheesh,5,main]satheesh
Thread[satheesh,5,main]satheesh
Thread[satheesh,5,main]satheesh
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)
```